# UpdateTime event don't working in videoJS

Tags: jquery, html, video.js

I'm using videoJS, but I don't get the Time Update event working.

This is how I defined the video:

I tested several of the solutions that are on Google and here, but nothing seems to work, like the following:

```
<script>
$('#testvid').on('timeupdate', function(){
    console.log('the time was updated to: ' + this.currentTime);
});

videojs('testvid').ready(function(){
    var myPlayer = this;
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the [video.js API](https://github.com/videojs/video.js/blob/master/docs/api/vjs.Player.md) and set up the event listener in the ready function.

```
videojs('testvid').ready(function(){
  var myPlayer = this;
  myPlayer.on('timeupdate', function(){
    console.log('the time was updated to: ' + myPlayer.currentTime());
  });
});
```

Comment: which is the lib I need to include to have access to the API? because if I do that with video-js.js file, I get the error that the browser doesn't know how to interpretate videojs('my_video_1') function.

Comment: You don't need to do anything special to enable the API. The argument passed to `videojs()` is the id of your player, so 'testvid' in your case.

Comment: I don't know how to do it works... The videojs works because the video is being reproduced, but the videojs api is not working. I'm including the js between <head> but the browser said "Uncaught ReferenceError: videojs is not defined"

Comment: I've just found that the following code is working in firefox but not in chrome: myVid=document.getElementById("mainvideo");
        myVid.addEventListener("timeupdate", function()
 {